# Return Array Values By Key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows (var_dump below):

```
array (size=3)
  'Test Field 1' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  'Test Field 2' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
      1 => string 'foobar' (length=6)
      2 => string 'barfoobar' (length=9)
  'Test Field 3' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'barfoo' (length=6)
      1 => string 'foobarfoobar' (length=12)
```

I would like to output the data, grouped by keys as follows:

- Test Field 1: foo
- Test Field 2: bar
- Test Field 3: barfoo
- Test Field 2: foobar
- Test Field 3: foobarfoobar
- Test Field 2: barfoobar

Basically, all of the 0 keys grouped together, then the 1 keys, then the 2 keys, etc.

The array won't always be set up this way, meaning there may be many more elements per array, or there may be only one, so it needs to be able to be dynamically populated.

A typical foreach loop gives me the data output as follows (not what I want):

- Test Field 1: foo
- Test Field 2: bar
- Test Field 2: foobar
- Test Field 2: barfoobar
- Test Field 3: barfoo
- Test Field 3: foobarfoobar

Comment: Get the size of the largest element. Then loop from 0 to that size, and inside that loop through the top-level elements, printing the Nth element of it if it exists.

Comment: Thank you! I think having it put in words that were not my own helped me wrap my head around the problem.

Comment: Share your code also?

Comment: I think I may have been typing it as you posted the comment. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The var_dump above is from the variable `$output`. To display the data as described above, I did the following:

```
$max = max( array_map( 'count', $output ) ); // get the max number of keys in the array
$repeat = 0; //set to start with 0 key
for( $repeat; $repeat<=$max; $repeat++ ){
    foreach($output as $key => $values){ //loop through the $output
        if ( isset( $values[$repeat] ) ){ // check if this exists
            echo $key . ': ' . $values[$repeat] . '<br />'; //display the key/values as needed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is tested code

```
$input = [
    'Test Field 1' => [
        'foo',
    ],
    'Test Field 2' => [
        'bar',
        'foobar',
        'barfoobar',
    ],
    'Test Field 3' => [
        'barfoo',
        'foobarfoobar',
    ],
];

function recursive_print($input)
{
    foreach ($input as $k => &$v) {
        echo "\n";
        echo $k. ':' . array_shift($v);

        if (!$v) {
            unset($input[$k]);
        }
    }


    if ($input) {
        recursive_print($input);
    }
}

recursive_print($input);
```